# Unable to include lubridate in Imports: in R package DESCRIPTION

Tags: r, import, package

In my R package I modified a function which uses 'year' from lubridate. The package builds and checks all right without the lubridate as it is a run time dependency

```
 Depends:
     R (>= 3.2.4)
 LazyData: TRUE
 Encoding: UTF-8
 RoxygenNote: 7.1.1
 Imports:
  dplyr,
  ggplot2,
  reshape2,
  yaml,
  gridExtra,
  rpart.plot,
  stats,
  utils
```

But when I include lubridate in the Imports:

```
 Depends:
     R (>= 3.2.4)
 LazyData: TRUE
 Encoding: UTF-8
 RoxygenNote: 7.1.1
 Imports:
  dplyr,
  ggplot2,
  reshape2,
  yaml,
  gridExtra,
  rpart.plot,
  stats,
  lubridate,
  utils
```

I get a NOTE as follows
"Namespace in Imports field not imported from: ‘lubridate’
All declared Imports should be used." and I don't see lubridate in the NAMESPACE file

Can I do without including lubridate? If not, how can I include it? Please let me know

Comment: How are you using `lubridate`?  If you use a function from it via `::`, it is usually caught.  The exception is if that only happens in the default argument to a function, in which case the check code was buggy but has been fixed in R-devel (to become R 4.3.0).